# Office.js Exchange On-Prem 2013 mailbox.item saveAsync

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an application for an organisation that is using Exchange 2013 on-premise and wants a 'simple' Outlook add-in that can be used to add some message headers to the message when the user clicks a button in compose mode.

Given the age of this, the only requirement set I have access to is 1.1 which is complicating matters.

I have managed to use `makeEwsRequestAsync` along with some handcrafted SOAP to set InternetHeaders on the message but this requires me to call `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()` to get an EWS ID and thanks to some dubious documentation on the MS site where the show the method being used in the 1.1 req set documentation, it turns out this method is only available in 1.3+.

Does anyone know of either a SOAP request I can craft by hand to send up to get the message saved as a draft and its itemId returned to me or perhaps getting something similar to `saveAsync` working in the 1.1 req set.

---

Edit 1: I did try using the Custom Properties interface before making manual EWS calls but these don't seem to be sent with the message when the user finally clicks send so those were discarded.

Comment: > to some dubious documentation <
I feel you, the documentation is the most confusing one I've seen so far. The officejs library has some serious limitations if using with Exchange2013, got trapped by that too.

Comment: Sorry, that's an error in the documentation. Thanks for reporting, we'll fix it. `item.itemId` can only be used in read mode until 1.3 (and in compose mode when the item is already saved).

You can set custom properties on the message and use an add-in in read mode to load the custom properties back again. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.3/office.context.mailbox.item#loadcustompropertiesasynccallback-usercontext

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have used custom properties whilst composing, but as I said in the original question, these are not translated into X-Headers and the InternetHeader interface is 1.8+. I can work around this with a manual soap call using `makeEwsRequestAsync` but I still need to get the item id from somewhere, are you saying it is simply impossible to do so in 1.1?

Comment: Yes, they will not translate into headers. If you only want to set some information on the message that will be accessed by the same add-in on message read, you can use the customProperties API. Otherwise you will have to move to the 1.3 requirement set. We have posted this as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that's an error in the documentation. Thanks for reporting, we'll fix it. `item.itemId` can only be used in read mode until 1.2 API set (and in compose mode when the item is already saved).

The only way to get the itemId for an email in compose mode is to use `saveAsync()`, so you will have to move to the 1.3 requirement set in order to set internet headers.